# Perl inheritance

Tags: perl

In Perl, given a package name "My::Package" in a scalar $myScalar what is the best why to determine if My::Package has a parent called "My::Package::Parent"? The restraints here are that My::Package may not already be loaded and that we don't know the required parameters for the class constructor.

Thanks

Comment: Until My::Package is loaded (e.g., via `use`), it *doesn't have any parents*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can't know what a class has for parent until the class exists, so you need to load the module that defines it. Then you can use the UNIVERSAL method `isa` to find if it inherits from `My::Package::Parent`.

```
my $class = 'My::Package';

my $file = $class;   # Or:
$file =~ s{::}{/}g;  #   eval "require $class;" or die $@;
$file .= '.pm';      #
require $file;       #

if ($class->isa('My::Package::Parent')) {
   ...
}
```

Reference:

- [require](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html)
- [UNIVERSAL](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?UNIVERSAL)

Answer (score 3):

I expect you'll want `isa()`, or maybe directly exploring `@ISA`, but check out `DOES()` and `can()` in `man perlobj` too.